# How to add Custom Button in each row in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I am trying to add Custom Button to each row of Kendo Grid, but I am not getting the desired output.So my requirement is to add dynamic buttons to each row and on clicking on these button I need to process few thing for which I need few column values to be passed to that button click.

I have tried something like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(o => o.Id);

    columns.Bound(o => o.TBRId).Width(100).Title(UI_Resources.ListLabel_TBRId);

    columns.Bound(o => o.THUQuantity).Width(50).Title(UI_Resources.ListLabel_THUQuantity).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
    columns.Bound(o => o.Id).ClientTemplate("<input width='50px' type='button' value= " + UI_Resources.Button_Details + " onclick='onDetailUnitClick(#= Id #);'  class='btn btnTable'  />").Width(50).Title("");
columns.Bound(o => o.IsPOD).ClientTemplate("#= AppendZeroPODButton(Id,IsPOD) #").Width(60).Title("");

 })

.Pageable()

.Sortable()

.Scrollable()

.Filterable()

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

    .Ajax()

            .Read(read => read.Action("GetUnitsForShipment", "POD",new { shipmentId = @Model, Mode = "POD" }))

          )

 )

/*JavaScript */

function onDetailUnitClick(Id) {
var podDateTime = $("#enteredPODDateTime").val();
var stopId = $("#hiddenStopId").val();
var mode = '';
if (typeof $("#hiddenMode").val() != 'undefined')
    mode = $("#hiddenMode").val();
window.location.href = "/POD/Details/" + Id + "?stopId=" + stopId + "&date=" + podDateTime + "&mode=" + mode;
  };

  function AppendZeroPODButton(Id, isPOD) {
if (isPOD == true) {
    return "<input width='100px' type='button' value= 'Zero POD' onclick='onPODUnitClick(" + Id + ",1);'  class='btn btnTable btn-success' disabled />";
}
else {

    return "<input width='100px' type='button' value= 'Zero POD' onclick='onPODUnitClick(" + Id + ",1);'  class='btn btnTable btn-danger'  />";
}}
```

Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong!!
It was working for Telerek MVC grids.

Thanks
Yogendra Singh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked if I change the ClientTemplate to

```
columns.Template(t => t.IsPOD).HeaderTemplate("").ClientTemplate(@"<a href='javascript: void(0)' class='btn btnTable' onclick='onDetailUnitClick(#= Id #)' title='button delete'>" + UI_Resources.Button_Details + " </a>").Title("").Width(50);
```

AND

```
columns.Bound(p => p.IsPOD).ClientTemplate("# if( IsPOD == true) { # <a href='javascript: void(0)' class='btn btnTable btn-success' onclick='onPODUnitClick(#= Id #, 1)' title='Zero POD'>" + UI_Resources.Button_ZeroPOD + "</a> # } else {# <a href='javascript: void(0)' class='btn btnTable btn-danger' onclick='onPODUnitClick(#= Id #, 1)' title='Zero POD'>" + UI_Resources.Button_ZeroPOD + "</a> # } #").Title("").Width(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add Custom button as well.Refer this http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html